# format date in php returned from mysqli

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I have a query that returns a date, and I'd like to format it before I display it to users on my page.  However, when I use format, the date appears to be null (displays year 1969).  Here is the code that gets the data:

```
$sql = 'SELECT u.username, td.postingText, td.createdOn, td.lastUpdated
        FROM threadDetails td, users u
        WHERE blogThreadId = ?
        AND td.userId = u.userId
        order by td.createdOn DESC';
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $blogThreadId);
$stmt->bind_result($username, $postingText, $createdOn, $lastUpdated);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    $rowofdata=array(
        'username' => $username,
        'postingText' => $postingText,
        'createdOn' => $createdOn,
        'lastUpdated' => $lastUpdated,
    );  
    $results[] = $rowofdata;
}   
$stmt->close();
```

When I print it out with the following code (in a different function):

```
foreach ($threadData as $threadDetailItem)
{
    $msg = sprintf ("<tr>%s %s %s %s %s </tr>\n",
        "<td>" . $threadDetailItem['threadTitle'] . "</td>", 
        "<td>" . $threadDetailItem['username'] . "</td>", 
        "<td>" . $threadDetailItem['createdOn'] . "</td>", 
        "<td>" . $threadDetailItem['threadCount'] . "</td>", 
        "<td>" . $threadDetailItem['lastUpdated'] . "</td>");
    echo $msg;
}
```

It prints out (for my created On or last Updated fields):

2012-04-15 16:14:55

When I replaced the portion of the sprintf line:

```
        "<td>" . $threadDetailItem['createdOn'] . "</td>",
```

with:

```
        "<td>" . date("F j, Y, g:i a", $threadDetailItem['createdOn']) . "</td>",
```

I get

"December 31, 1969, 7:33 pm" and a message in my phplog stating a non-well formed numeric value encountered.  What do I need to do get the the right date displayed correctly?  I've tried changing the sprintf from %s to %d, but that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Select the formatted date directly from MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format   Anything else will waste cpu time to do roundtrip conversions from string->native->string->etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `$threadDetailItem['createdOn']` is a string, and the `date()` function expects a numeric timestamp. Use the `strtotime()` PHP function to convert the string to a timestamp first:

```
date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($threadDetailItem['createdOn']))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was it, and it is fixed.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The string first must be converted to Timestamp by using `strtotime` function.

```
$date=$variable['from-database'];
date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date))
```

Answer (score -1):

Php's date() function uses unix timestamp http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time, not date strings.

I would really recommend you to change your database schema to use a BIGINT instead and store your date information with date("U"). If you do you will get around the hazzel with date and locale formats.
You can use INT aswell but the system can handle dates after 2038 if you do.

You could use the strtotime() function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php.

```
date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($threadDetailItem['createdOn']))
```

However if your date is stored in the wrong locale it will give you the wrong answer.
Belive me when i say that date strings and locales can be a real mess.
That's why you should always store the date in unixtimestamp.

Comment: Disagree. You just need to make sure you have it set up correctly.